# Make a one to one mapping from string to enum variant without using a match statement

Tags: rust, enums, macros

I'm writing code to parse HTTP requests. I'd rather keep some things like request methods and response codes as enums because of their exhaustibility.

But it also means that for each of those enums I would have to make a `From<String>` implementation. The obvious way to do it is to match against a plethora of constant strings. That seems like a lot of almost identical code which I would want to factor out.

Someone suggested I use a macro to do it, but my knowledge of rust macros is limited so it made me question some things:

- How can I ensure the argument is of type `&str` or `String`? Macros can take expressions, but I don't want to use `type_name` and panic if it doesn't match as it seems to be a very dirty fix.
- How can I convert a string to a token stream? So far I've seen that the `proc_macro` crate offers that functionality, but is it possible to do with simple declarative macro?
- Is it possible to achieve one to one mapping by any other means? I hoped I could pre-initialize enum variants with some known values like in Java.

Comment: I think you can use this crate (https://github.com/Peternator7/strum). If you want to implement it on your own, use this repo as a reference.

Comment: Side note: you probably want `From<&'_ str>` not `From<String>`.

Comment: As far as "without `match`," that seems like a bit of an arbitrary requirement. Aside from `strum`, you could also implement this without `match` by creating a global `HashMap<String, T>` for each enum type `T` and having the `From` implementation just do a lookup on that map. This may or may not be faster depending on how many variants there are, and how efficient the code generated from the `match` is.

Comment: What are you going to do? Show us some code. Java enums are different to Rust enums. It's more like a Rust struct with one constructor for each value.

Comment: What strings are you trying to convert into enums? Request methods like `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, etc.? Request URLs like `/api/v1/user/id/1234`? Some examples of strings and the corresponding enums would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnKugelman, yes - request methods, but also some common headers like User-Agent, ContentLength, and etc. Perhaps the standard response codes

Comment: @Aitch, yes that exactly what I've meant. Since the java Enum classes are initialized with known constant variable I could compare with. I know rust Enums are different, and arguably much more powerful - but I'm not sure if I could make a separate static variable associated with every Enum variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to use a library for this. You can write the macro yourself, but someone else has already made a battle-tested version of what you're trying to do.

Use [strum](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum)'s [EnumString](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.2/strum_macros/derive.EnumString.html) derive:

In `Cargo.toml`:

```ini
[dependencies]
strum = "0.24"
strum_macros = "0.24"
```

In your source code: (eg `main.rs`)

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;
use strum_macros::EnumString;

#[derive(Debug, EnumString)]
enum MyEnum {
  Foo,
  Bar,
  Baz,
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(MyEnum::from_str("Foo").unwrap());
}
```

Gives you

```
[src/main.rs:12] MyEnum::from_str("Foo").unwrap() = Foo
```

For more details see [The documentation for the `FromString` derive](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.24.2/strum_macros/derive.EnumString.html) and [strum's readme](https://github.com/Peternator7/strum/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: I'm not sure the strings here are the variant names. It's possible the OP wants to convert URLs into enums, for example `/api/v1/user/id/1234` into `Request::GetUser(1234)`, something like that.

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for not reading through the question properly. Strum does have an option to serialize other strings into a given variant with `#[strum(serialize = "whatever")]` but that's a bit of a stretch for http parsing.